How many different rectangles can be formed by connecting four dots in a 4x4 square array of dots, such that the sides are parallel to the grid?
The question goes as such: How many different rectangles can be formed by connecting four of the dots in a $4 \times 4$ square array of dots, such that the sides of the rectangle are parallel to the sides of the grid?
I am confused as to why my answer is incorrect: $$\dfrac{16\times6\times3\times1}{4!} = 12.$$
My thought process goes as such: first select any 16 dots in the array. Then you have 6 possible options for the second dot. Then you have 3 possible options for the third dot. And finally, the last dot only has one possible option. Then divide by $4!$ as the order doesn't matter.
The correct answer is 36 obtained by $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ which I understand as they are using the horizontal and vertical lines. However I'm confused why my answer is off by a factor of $3$.

Because for any given rectangle, your method can't choose the 4 corners in $4!$ different orders. The first point you choose and the last point you choose must be diagonally opposite. (At least the way I read your recipe; it's possible to read it so that the first and last points must be adjacent, but the end result is the same.)
So you should've divided by $4\cdot2$ instead: choose which of the corners comes first, then which of the two adjacent corners comes second, the remaining two have their order forced.

Thank you for the response. However, I am confused by when you say "choose which of the corners comes first, then which of the two adjacent corners comes second, the remaining two have their order forced." Suppose I pick any corner first, then I pick an adjacent corner, I don't see how the other two points are forced. Because I could choose the third point or fourth point first, then the other is forced. Thus there are $4\times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ ways.

As @Arthur observed, your approach to selecting the corners does not allow you to permute them freely.  The assumption that you can choose from among 16, 6, 3, and 1 options encodes an in-order traversal around the perimeter of the rectangle, so the degrees of freedom associated with each distinct rectangle are two: at which corner to start (4 choices), and in which direction to travel (2 choices).
If you want to perform the computation by corner selection instead of by edge selection, then I would suggest instead proceeding by recognizing that each rectangle can be identified by just two non-adjacent corners.  That gives you
$$ \frac{16\times 9}{2 \times 2} = 36$$
different rectangles as 16 choices for one corner, 9 choices for a second corner not in the same row or column as the first, 2 orders for that selection, and 2 distinct diagonals for each rectangle.

Thank you for the answer! Could you explain what you mean by there are "2 distinct diagonals for each rectangle?" I understand why you have to divide by two to account for the order of selection of the corner of the rectangles, but not the other two diagonals like you mentioned.

@LeoLiang, Consider a grid-oriented rectangle.  It is completely defined by either the (top-left, bottom-right) vertex pair or the (top-right, bottom-left) vertex pair.  The $16 \times 9$ counts both orders of both diagonals of each rectangle.
